# How to reduce edges and make a face out of it?

Tags: edges

[image: My spaceship with too many edges]

Have lots of edges in my starship mesh, as shown in the red box.
How could I reduce them and make one rounded face out of it?

Comment: You might be better off deleting the messed up section and re-extruding. Use `Alt`+`M` to merge selected vertices.

Comment: You could try to unsubdivide with Ctrl+E

Comment: You have a ton of 0-area faces along the edge where you added more geometry.  I agree with Novice, you are probably better off re-extruding.

Comment: You might be looking for the Dissolve Edges operator, on the <kbd>x</kbd> menu.

Comment: One more thing to try (if deletion isn't the best) is to select such area and use `W` *> Smooth* tool (also in the `T` panel). Faces with 0 area will reveal themselves because of smoothing, and others with bad topology will become better (quite a bit sometimes)

Answer (score 1):

Just as Tainin said it is not possible to make a curved/bent/folded surface without joining two or more vertices with an edge. However you can make a low Poly model and use smooth shading (in tools menu) to give a more curved shade effect. Or perhaps the normal maps might help depending upon the purpose of your 'Ship'.

Answer (score -1):

i don't think it is possible to have a curved face without the extra edges. more vertices and edges add more resolution/detail to the model. you could try selecting the faces, pressing x and selecting dissolve faces.[image]

[image]