# How to lower the polygon number but keep smoothness?

Tags: faces, subdivision-surface, polycount

I might have put too many polygons in the mesh and now it won't compile, so I need to lower the polygon number. Is it possible to do something to create an effect which works the opposite as the subdivision surface, but keeping the smooth surface?

Comment: maybe a Decimate modifier ?

Comment: Could you post the settings or a picture please? I'm new and I have no idea what I'm doing most of the time xd

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/17788/how-to-optimize-a-mesh-by-merging-objects-and-or-reducing-faces and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/33466/how-to-reduce-edges-and-make-a-face-out-of-it

Answer (score 2):

You can use the **Decimate** modifier: [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/modifiers/generate/decimate.html)'s the documentation.

[image]

It has three different ways of operation: *Collapse*, *Un-Subdivide* and *Planar*. Choose the one the most suits your needs and change the parameters until you reach the right compromise between **smoothness** of the surface and **face count** (which is updated live in the modifier box).

Click "Apply" when you are happy with the result. Please note that, if you are using UV maps, you should use the **Planar** mode and select **Delimit: UV**.

Answer (score 1):

- Add a decimate modifier

[image: the Add modifier menu]

- click the *Un-Subdivide* button
- increase the *Iterations* field to two

[image: decimate modifier]

Comment: Oh that was perfect! Nowe the PC doesn't lag anymore and the mesh is still smooth hahaha Does anything bad happen if I increase the iterations from 2 to a higher number in order to get even less polygons?

Comment: No : it's its job ;-)